# Copy Laravel and rename it

Tags: laravel, copy, laravel-5.1, rename

What is the best and safest way to copy a laravel project and rename it.

For instance I do have a laravel project name

> "gugu"

and I want to copy it to another system and rename it to

> "master"

Comment: You want to change namespace or what do you mean by 'rename' ?

Comment: rename the project, the top folder

Comment: Than just rename the folder name. That should not affect laravel project.

Comment: You sure?I think it did affect last time I did it

Comment: get this error InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [auth.login] not found.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. I do It several time and not have problem

Comment: I would just be careful to change the folder which your webserver is pointing to. If you do not change this in nginx or apache maybe this will cause it to break!

Comment: ok I will try it but create  a backup first ill let you know tomorrow

Comment: I get this error InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [auth.login] not found.